# openMP license information

Tags: c++, licensing, openmp

I would like to use openMP with compiler VS2010. what is license status for openMP? can it be freely used in commercial software, and can you point at the relevant doc?

thanks and regarsd

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenMP by itself is an API specification, so there's no license for using it. The implementation provided by your compiler is subject to the same license of the latter, so with Visual Studio you can of course use it in a commercial software.

Couldn't find relevant source to point out.